# .NET Same version nuget package to two projects in one solution

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

We have a solution with two projects (both version .net 4.6.2).
When installing a nuget package from our private Nuget Feed to either one of the projects, it works.

If we try to install the same package version into both projects, then package gets installed into one of them, and the other one gives error : "**Error        Could not install package 'OurInternalPackageName 1.0.1.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**   ".

We tried installing nuget using 'Manage packages for solution' option, manage nuget packages for projects separately but the result is still the same.

Changing .NET framework versions does not help.
Clearing Nuget cache did not help as well.

The workaround we are using now: install package to one of the projects, and then install a lower version of a package to another project.

We tested this with 'Automapper' Nuget, tried to install into both projects and it worked (Same version got installed into both projects).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to show `.csproj` files of the targets, etc. `OurInternalPackageName` suggests you're going to have to show details about that as well.

Comment: Which packages are throwing this error? All of them or certain ones?

Comment: After some testing it seems to be an issue with the way we create nuget packages, because all of our nuget packages gives this error. 

We did some testing: 
- Created an empty solution with 2 projects, both version 4.6.2. 
- Created a nuget package from scratch (Just an empty project). 
- Tried to install new nuget package to both projects, it gets installed into one, and the other one gives same exception.
Adding `.csproj` files, as well as `.nupkg` in the following comment.

Comment: [Solution .sln file contents](https://pastebin.com/t8QXEtcc)

[ProjectA .csproj file](https://pastebin.com/Z88pR4kp)

[ProjectB .csproj file](https://pastebin.com/mNYWKJTR)

[nupkg file contents](https://pastebin.com/iVHc7i84)